# Remove first row of all certain duplicate entries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My issue is that I have duplicate entries in my table. However, it's not that simple. Some are valid duplicates while others are not. For example, `E Pearl River, NY` and `East Pearl River, NY` are the same city while `Bardonia, NY` and `Nanuet, NY` are not. So, if I removed ALL duplicates, it would remove valid cities like Bardonia.

My question is, does anyone know a way (in SQL or any programming language) to loop through each row and do the following:

- Check if row is duplicate
- Check if there is a partial match for `city` (i.e. E **Pearl River, NY** and East **Pearl River, NY**)
- Remove **first** of the duplicate rows
- If there is **no** partial match for `city` (i.e. Bardonia, NY and Nanuet, NY), move along.

## Before

```
+—————————+——————————————————————+
| zipcode |        city          |
+—————————+——————————————————————+
|  10956  | E Pearl River, NY    |
|  10956  | East Pearl River, NY |
|  10977  | Spring Valley, NY    |
|  10954  | Bardonia, NY         |
|  10954  | Nanuet, NY           |
+—————————+——————————————————————+
```

## After

```
+—————————+——————————————————————+
| zipcode |        city          |
+—————————+——————————————————————+
|  10956  | East Pearl River, NY |
|  10977  | Spring Valley, NY    |
|  10954  | Bardonia, NY         |
|  10954  | Nanuet, NY           |
+—————————+——————————————————————+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy solution for your problem as it involves natural language processing.

How do you define **E Pearl River, NY** is duplicate for **East Pearl River, NY**? What about East and West Pearl River? For natural language processing you should take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

For fairly easy (but not necessarily very accurate) solution, you could try implementing simple [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) measure.

Comment: Thought this might be a problem -- I will look into these, thank you.